# THREE.js: How to change color of Face while ignoring Material color?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to change the color of a single Face in a Geometry.

I initialized my Mesh with Geometry and Material like below:

```
const geometry = new THREE.Geometry({
  // some options
});
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: '0xff0000', // red
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
  flatShading: true,
});
```

Then I found the target face I want to color using mouse coordinates and raycaster's intersection finding method.

Finally, I tried to apply a color on to my target face:

```
targetFace.color.setHex(0x0000ff);
mesh.material.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
```

I want the target face to change color from red to blue, but the face ends up being black. I did some googling and found out that the color of the face gets "multiplied" by the color originally set on the Material, ending up in a mix of the two colors.

How can I avoid this and change the color of the face to the exact color I want?

**Current result**

[image]

**Expected result**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're giving the material two conflicting commands. Right now you're telling the material to render a base color with `color: 0xff0000` but you're also telling the faceColor to be `0x0000ff`. When these two values are multipled, you get black:

```
0xff0000 x 0x0000ff = 0x000000

// Broken down, it's the same as this:
1 x 0 = 0
0 x 0 = 0
0 x 1 = 0
```

What you need to do is set the base color to `0xffffff` and then set *each* face color to the value you want:

```
0xffffff X 0x0000ff = 0x0000ff // Blue
0xffffff X 0xff0000 = 0xff0000 // Red
```

Or more simply, if you want to avoid color multiplication altogether, just don't declare the base color by removing this line: `color: '0xff0000', // red`. With `vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,` you can then just assign colors to each face without worrying about multiplication.